# Types of Feynman diagrams in QED?

Tags: resource-recommendations, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

I am looking for some kind of database which covers a large set of possible Feynman diagrams in QED. Not necessarily the value of the Feynman diagram, I am just looking for the diagrams themselves which will help me have a better intuition on the graphical structure of these diagrams.

Comment: Tree level and one-loop diagrams are present (and quite thoroughly discussed) in standard QFT textbooks (Peskin & Schroeder for example and also Schwartz). If you want to take a look in two-loops diagrams these can be found in papers. For instance, some two-loops diagrams are in page 3 of this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0305072.

Comment: I am looking for something more general than this, something which characterizes types or sequences of diagrams.

Comment: Well, connected diagrams (which are the ones we really care about) are often classified as being either one-particle irreducible (1PI) or a string of 1PI diagrams connected by propagators. Don't know whether it helps, maybe you already know this.